# How can I prevent my fixed positioned elements from scrolling when the browser is resized?

Tags: html, css, css-position, fixed, horizontal-scrolling

I must start off by saying I'm on a HUGE learning curve with this, and the website project is in my spare time as a present to somebody, so my knowledge is limited, although I think I understand the basics. 
ALSO please note that I do have another more basic, less interesting site which is already built as a back-up so I won't be broken-hearted if I'm told all my code is rubbish and I need to start again!

I'm creating a one-page, horizontally-scrolling portfolio site for a make-up artist, which requires me to have a fixed banner with my menu listings on the left hand side, and with javascript, the page scrolls nice and smoothly to the relevant section.

Everything looks great on my screen resolution, with my browser at the right size, but I've noticed that if I shrink the browser window down, the fixed navigation banner starts to scroll out of place, while everything else stays together as it should.

The end result should be that everything stays in its place, with the only 'moving part' being the content on the scrolling section, so when the browser is resized, everything either re-sizes or at least scrolls together.

I've played around with wrapping everything in a content div and I've experimented with different positioning, but nothing seems to be working.

Here's my basic html layout for the sections:

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="banner"> <!--this is the fixed nav banner-->
<ul>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="portfolio" class="bigpanel">
<div id="portfolioimages">
    <!--IMAGES GO HERE-->
</div>
</div>

<div id="about" class="panel">
</div>

<div id="testimonials" class="bigpanel">
</div>

<div id="contact" class="bigpanel">
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

...and the CSS:

```
body {
    width: 15000px;
    height: 580px;
    background-color: #fcf4f1;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 2% 0 5% 0;
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 935px;
    top: 645px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#banner {
    position: fixed;
    height: 580px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 45px 0px 0px 20px;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.panel {
    width: 930px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 242px;
    padding-right: 1040px;
    margin-top: 45px;
}

.bigpanel {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 242px;
    padding-right: 1040px;
    margin-top:45px;
}
```

[Pic of how the site is at the correct size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w1mj.jpg)

[...and a pic of how it looks when it's squished in height!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAd3S.png)

I've tried to be as thorough as possible so sorry for the long one!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you put this in a fiddle i can play with it

Comment: Seems like what you want is for the banner to be fixed in the horizontal direction but not in the vertical direction, so that it always remains 20px from  the left of you window, but not necessary 45px from the top of your window. Is this correct? If so, this can't be done with HTML and CSS alone. Are you using Javascript as well?

Comment: @SamJacobs That's great of you but when I said I'm on a huge learning curve - I don't even know how to do that haha. I'll look into it now.

Comment: @snookieordie I think you might be right, although the eventual goal for the site would be that everything fits within the set height.

The goal is that the main body of the site (everything excluding background colour and the copyright notice in the footer) is within a horizontal strip across the middle (currently 580px tall) and the whole thing only moves horizontally, and if one thing is resized, everything resizes together.

And javascript is being used simply for the horizontal smooth scrolling currently!

Comment: jsfiddle.net, put the correct code in the right places, hit save, then post link :)

Comment: @SamJacobs http://jsfiddle.net/5oa0pcg2/ there we go, I've added more content so you have something to actually play with. 

ALTHOUGH when it's viewed in full screen for some reason the problem I'm discussing doesn't exist so I don't know how you'll know when it's fixed! (the about page is messed up but that's not the issue)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know whether I have the answer that will work for everyone but it certainly has for me.

I basically had a long look at how I'd defined the widths and heights for basically all elements in my website and worked out that although the widths needed to be fixed for the main body and the banner, the height could be responsive depending on the viewport size.

I wrapped everything in a very wide wrapper div, with a height set to 100%, but set the body height to 84vh, with a max-height of 700px (so my images can have the same max-height and always look good).

This way I could also set the banner to height: 84vh with a max-height of 700px so it never overflows, but always sizes down.

I set the margin for my wrapper to centre it vertically, and now whilst everything fits inside its containers, there's no vertical scroll!

I'm sure a lot of it is an ugly solution, caused by my bad coding but it works now!

Answer (score 0):

I thing you have to play with the `top` poperty on you `#banner` div by putting it to `0`. This work only with positions like `fixed`, `absolute`, `relative`, etc. What it will do is to fix you div at the top of your browser window, no matter what. **It is the "top padding" (disantce) you div will have relativly to the to of the screen.**

So you should just add

```
top: 0;
```

to

```
#banner
```

and it should work!

If you want an exemple of it's efficacity, I recommend you to look at this codepen: http://codepen.io/Symsym/pen/LsjCK

Cheers! and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<div class="banner"> <!--this is the fixed nav banner-->
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a href="#testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class='content'>
  <div id="portfolio" class="bigpanel">
  <div id="portfolioimages">
      <!--IMAGES GO HERE-->
  </div>
  </div>

  <div id="about" class="panel">
    about
  </div>

  <div id="testimonials" class="bigpanel">
   testimonials
  </div>

  <div id="contact" class="bigpanel">
   contact
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
 footer is here!!
</div>
```

css code:

```
body {
    background-color: '#fcf4f1';
    overflow:hidden;
}

a{
  text-decoration:none;
}

li{
  list-style:none;
}

.banner {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: '#ccc';
    opacity: 0.8;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    top:20px;
    left:0;
}

.content{
  width:800px;
  margin-left:200px;
  overflow:auto;
  float:left;
}

.panel {
    margin-top:10px;
    width: 930px;
    float: left;
}

.bigpanel {
    float: left;
    margin-top:20px;
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background:red;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

you can scroll on content.